# ServiceStack IServiceGateway in Non Service/Non Controller and IOC

Tags: servicestack, funq

I have a console app with hangfire and service stack services into.  Hangfire has its own IOC Adapter Implementations which has been integrated into a Funq adapter.  I'm trying to use an IGatewayService to make calls to an inproc service.

The gateway is always null.

```
public class Tests
{
    public IServiceGateway gateway { get; set; }
    public Tests()
    {
        gateway =  HostContext.TryResolve<IServiceGateway>(); //tried this along with every type of registration

    }
    public void Test3() {
       // I want to use gateway here to call an inproc service
    }
}
```

I've tried:

```
Container.Register<IServiceGatewayFactory>(x => new TestServiceGatewayFactory())
            .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);

            Container.Register<Tests>(new Tests() { gateway = Container.Resolve<IServiceGateway>() });
```

And some other non funq adapters and the gateway is always null.  I could create the gateway in the register `new TestServiceGateway()` but it requires an `IRequest`.  If I pass null there it won't work either.

The hangfire call is simple:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<Tests>((t) => t.Test3(), Cron.Yearly(12, 12));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API to get the Service Gateway is:

```
HostContext.AppHost.GetServiceGateway(Request);
```

Where `Request` is the ServiceStack `IRequest` which you can create from an ASP.NET Request outside of ServiceStack with:

```
var request = HttpContext.Current.ToRequest();
```

Or you can create a Mock Request with:

```
var request = new MockHttpRequest();
```

Comment: If there is no HttpContext ?  This is running inside of a hangfire job..

Comment: @lucuma I've updated my answer to include a `MockHttpRequest`

Comment: Thank you that helped me track it down.  I ended up with `LightContainer.Register<Tests>((x)=>new Tests()
            { gateway= LightContainer.GetInstance<IServiceGatewayFactory>().GetServiceGateway(new MockHttpRequest())});`  The same would have worked with funq just that I am using both LightInject and Funq.